# nested object under path is not of nested type

Tags: elasticsearch

i created a index

```
    {
        "user": {
            "mappings": {
                "_doc": {
                    "_all": {
                        "enabled": false
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "store": true,
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "child": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "age": {
                                    "store": true,
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "gender": {
                                    "store": true,
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and add a doc

```
    {
        "name":"jack",
        "child":[
            {
                "age":0,
                "gender":1
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I execute a query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "child",
            "ignore_unmapped":true,
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "child.age": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it's always return this error:

failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [child] is not of nested type

When I don't add any documents，it's worked,but when i add any doc with the `nesed`, it's always return the error,  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does the call `GET user/_mapping` return?

Comment: @zyee can you please share your index mapping, and which version of elasticsearch are you using? I tried and tested the above mapping and index data in version 7.8, and it is working fine.